# Need help finding a windows struct

Tags: windows, struct

What I know about it:

```
struct unknown_struct
{
    struct _KAPC apc;
    struct _KEVENT event;
    char unknown[2056];
};
```

So first a kernel apc struct then a kernel event struct and the total size is 0x878 (2168) bytes. Anybody know a struct on 64-bit windows that matches this description? Thanks.

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. I am sure this struct doesn't stand alone without ever getting used by code. You could arguably look at tools like PDBRipper and modify them to look for structs of a given size. I reckon your struct ought to be in `ntoskrnl.exe` symbols, right?

Comment: Yeah it was a custom struct nothing to do with microsoft. How to mark as answered?

Comment: Only an answer can be marked as the accepted one. Instead you could mark it for deletion, if you wanted.